# How can I have wordpress print posts whose IDs appear in an array?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an array of post IDs contained in $postarray.  I would like to print the posts corresponding to these IDs in Wordpress.
The code I am using is as follows:

```
query_posts(array('post__in' => $postarray));
if (have_posts()) :
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        the_title();
        the_excerpt();
    endwhile;
endif;
```

Despite this, the loop prints the most recent posts and not the posts contained in the array.  How can I have wordpress utilize the post IDs I supply in the array and print those posts in order?

Comment: I keep typing answers, but that should work. you might want to try making a new WP Query class.

Comment: Tried new WP_Query(); - no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to break out of the standard WP Loop for this...

Try and use the **get_post()** function which takes the ID of a post and returns an object containing a the details of the post in the usual OBJECT or Associate or Numeric Array format.

See **[full-explanation of get_post()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post)**.

You can come up with a custom routine to parse each item in the array. Here's a brief example:

```
function get_posts_by_ids( $postarray = null ) {
    if( is_array( $postarray ) )
        foreach( $postarray as $post ) {
            $post_details = get_post( $post[0] );

            // Title
            echo $post_details->post_title;
            //Body
            echo $post_details->post_content ;
        }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: When I run your code I get a "Only variables can be passed by reference" error on this line: $post_details = get_post( $post[0] );

Comment: Ooops!! Silly mistake... since I'm using an iterator, no need of the index i.e. $post[0]. You should use $post_details = get_post( $post ); instead.

Comment: I should have noticed that.  Thanks.